# Plot equation showing a circle

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, equation

The following formula is used to classify points from a 2-dimensional space:

```
f(x1,x2) = np.sign(x1^2+x2^2-.6)
```

All points are in space `X = [-1,1] x [-1,1]` with a uniform probability of picking each x.

Now I would like to visualize the circle that equals:

```
0 = x1^2+x2^2-.6
```

The values of x1 should be on the x-axis and values of x2 on the y-axis.

It must be possible but I have difficulty transforming the equation to a plot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to plot 2 variables on a plane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870472/how-to-plot-2-variables-on-a-plane)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a contour plot, as follows (based on the examples at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 0.6
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
plt.show()
```

This yields the following graph

[image]

Lastly, some general statements:

1. `x^2` does not mean what you *think* it does in python, you have to use `x**2`.
2. `x1` and `x2` are terribly misleading (to me), especially if you state that `x2` has to be on the y-axis.
3. (Thanks to Dux) You can add `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')` to make the figure actually look circular, by making the axis equal.

Comment: i am slightly embarrassed that i did not think of this... Way better solution!

Comment: @Dux I have a similar plot in my standard recipe book, I just had to modify it a bit (my initial answer was more complex than required). The approach that you suggested will also work (if you connect your functions) and yours is easier to understand for most of the users ;)

Comment: Thanks. Seem a traight forward way of making it.
Using '**' changed the output of the text when I tried to post the question.

Comment: Use `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')` before calling `plt.show()` to achieve a circular circle...

Comment: @Sinisj you can use the ` sign to surround a piece of text, yielding `x**2`

Comment: Isn't that a *very* inefficient way to draw a circle? You need to create two grids of 10000 variables and then run a contour algorithm on it. See my answer for a different approach.

Comment: @hitzg You are correct on that. However, I assume that when someone asks a plotting question performance is not such a big issue (unless their code contains a `savefig`). Therefore, I stuck with this option as (in my opinion) it's a quite easy to understand approach.

Comment: What should I do if I want to overlay a circle of different radius and specify its radius on the corresponding contour as a label manually?

Comment: @srinivasuu Just add a second plot and manually edit your labels. However, if you want more than that you'll have to ask a new question ;)

Answer (score 16):

The solution of @BasJansen certainly gets you there, it's either very inefficient (if you use many grid points) or inaccurate (if you use only few grid points).

You can easily draw the circle directly. Given `0 = x1**2 + x**2 - 0.6` it follows that `x2 = sqrt(0.6 - x1**2)` (as Dux stated).

But what you really want to do is to transform your cartesian coordinates to polar ones.

```
x1 = r*cos(theta)
x2 = r*sin(theta)
```

if you use these substitions in the circle equation you will see that `r=sqrt(0.6)`.

So now you can use that for your plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# theta goes from 0 to 2pi
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# the radius of the circle
r = np.sqrt(0.6)

# compute x1 and x2
x1 = r*np.cos(theta)
x2 = r*np.sin(theta)

# create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x1, x2)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this exactly as efficient as plotting `x1` and `x2` in @Bas Jansen's or my answer since you still plot on a cartesian grid and interpolation between these points will be linear instead of curved? You simply showed a maybe more elegant way of calculating the points on the circle...

Comment: All solutions have the same efficiency in *drawing* the circle. However, @Bas Jansen's answer is very inefficient in *creating* the data. Your solution is very similar to mine, the only difference is in my solution the points (which make up the circle) are equally spaced. You'll see the difference when you show the points (with `plt.plot(x, y, '.')` and `ax.set_aspect(1)`)

Comment: And have you tried closing the circle with your method?

Answer (score 5):

How about drawing x-values and calculating the corresponding y-values?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100, endpoint=True)
y = np.sqrt(-x**2. + 0.6)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, -y)
```

produces

[image]

This can obviously be made much nicer, but this is only for demonstration...

Answer (score 5):

```
# x**2  + y**2 = r**2
r = 6
x = np.linspace(-r,r,1000)
y = np.sqrt(-x**2+r**2)
plt.plot(x, y,'b')
plt.plot(x,-y,'b')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Plotting a circle using complex numbers

**The idea: multiplying a point by complex exponential ([image]) rotates the point on a circle**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_pts=20 # number of points on the circle
ps = np.arange(num_pts+1)
# j = np.sqrt(-1)
pts = np.exp(2j*np.pi/num_pts *(ps))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(pts.real, pts.imag , '-o')
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image]