# How can I keep the grid spacing consistent in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I use this code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 0.6
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
plt.show()
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092899/plot-equation-showing-a-circle), it works, but the spacing on the graph is distorted based on the window size. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to adjust the aspect ratio, which you can do using `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')`:

```
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]