# Plotting high order, implicit polynomial functions in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using Python, is it possible to plot implicit equations in *x* and *y*?

E.g.,
                                  *x³ y² + 3 x y + 9 x + x⁴ y⁴ + x⁴ + 3 = 0*

or, using a Python-like notation

```
x**3*y**2 + 3*x*y + 9*x + x**4*y**4 + 3 = 0
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: You probably want to look at [Plotting a polynomial in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088261/plotting-a-polynomial-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can plot an implicit function using the external library
[SymPy](https://pypi.org/project/sympy/), namely using
`sympy.plot_implicit` that in turn uses Matplotlib under the
hood:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot_implicit
x, y = symbols('x y')
plot_implicit(x**3*y**2+3*x*y+9*x+x**4*y**4+x**4+3, x, y)
```

[image]

Another option, less direct than the use of SymPy, is to stretch the usage of `plt.contour` in Matplotlib

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   ...: import numpy as np 
   ...:  
   ...: %matplotlib 
   ...:  
   ...: X = np.linspace(-4, 4, 201) 
   ...:  
   ...: x, y = np.meshgrid(X, X)                                                          

In [2]: z = x**3*y**2+3*x*y+9*x+x**4*y**4+x**4+3                                          

In [3]: plt.contour(x, y, z, (0,))                                                        
Out[3]: <matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet at 0x7fb866c805d0>
```

(note that `(0,)` is a tuple containing all the values for which you want to draw an isoline)

[image]

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try this out, thank you so much!

Comment: Two weeks later.  Have you tried my solutions? Did it work for you?