# Plotting 2 or more functions in the same graph

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I would like to plot 2 curves in the same figure with the following code:

```
import sympy as syp


x, y = syp.symbols('x, y')

my_function = syp.exp(-(x-2)**2)*syp.exp(-(y-3)**2) + 2*syp.exp(-(x+1)**2)*syp.exp(-(y-1)**2) 

gradient_1 = syp.diff(my_function, x)
gradient_2 = syp.diff(my_function, y)


curve_1 = syp.plot_implicit(syp.Eq(gradient_1, 0))
curve_2 = syp.plot_implicit(syp.Eq(gradient_2, 0))
```

What I see is only the first plot, while I would like to have both the curves in the same picture, maybe also with a grid if possible.
Any ideas?

<sub>Note: with matplotlib it's very easy, but I cannot find any specific example for the function `syp.plot_implicit`</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might work if you do:

```
>>> curve_1.extend(curve_2)
>>> curve_1.show()
```

However mixing implicit plots might not be implemented yet.

Be aware that your `curve_1` and `curve_2` are not what sympy considers "single curves" i.e. `Series` instance, but rather "collections of a number of curves", i.e. `Plot` instances.

You can also extract the matplotlib objects from `curve_1._backend.fig` and other `_backend` attributes.

In conclusion, there is a nice API to do what you want, but probably the methods behind it are not finished yet.

Comment: Yes, it works, that's great! I also found another way by using "pyplot.contour" (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527/is-it-possible-to-plot-implicit-equations-using-matplotlib) ), but it requires the manual calculation of the gradient, so your method is still the best one. Do you know if it can be plotted with a grid? I don't see this option in the parameters that can be passed to the function...

Answer (score 7):

Another, perhaps more efficient way, would be to compute both at the same time using `Or`

```
plot_implicit(Or(Eq(gradient_1, 0), Eq(gradient_2, 0)))
```

Comment: is this still the best way to go about this or have things changed?

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

`curve_1.append(curve_2[0])
curve_1.show()`