# pyplot how to plot function hard to be simplified as y = f(x)

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, how to plot `sin(x^2 + y^2) = cos(x * y)`?
It is hard to simplify this function to `y = f(x)`.

I think this is not a duplicate to [Is it possible to plot implicit equations using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527), since my question is about `y = f(x)` and not `z = f(x, y)`

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2484602/5103802) really good and suitable for you.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar I think it is not a duplicate, since this function is `y = f(x)`, not `z = f(x, y)`

Comment: The first answer from that duplicate question is directly usable. You have `F = sin(x**2 + y**2)` and `G=cos(x * y)`, such that `F-G ==0`. So you are plotting `contour(X, Y, (F - G), [0])` just as in that answer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, I marked this question as duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should then mark the answer below as correct, as it's not really answering the question, right?

Answer (score 0):

Contour function may be used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(-1., 1.)
y = np.linspace(-1., 1.)[:, None] # y has to be 2d array
plt.contour(x, y.flatten(), np.sin(x*x+y*y) - np.cos(x*y))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: OP explicitely said they don't want `z = f(x, y)`. Why are you then answering by giving the solution for the case they don't want? Especially as there already was the link to the question present which shows the correct answer.

Comment: Where you find z? It is f(x,y)=0.

Comment: That's exactly my point. The code from your answer produces contours for `z = f(x, y)` with z equal to -0.8, -0.6, -0.4 etc., while the question is about `f(x,y)=0`.

Comment: Exactly! But you misunderstand something cos all these lines are satisfy to equation f(x,y)=0. Equation is trigonometric and have a lot of resolutions. Contour plot is allowed to show them with desired steps like here step is near 1/5.According to your thesis x^2+y^2=1 is a f(x,y)=z equation but it is doubtful.

Comment: You may surely call each of the lines a solution to `g(x,y)=0`. In that case however, `g` is different for each line. Say we have `F = sin(x**2 + y**2)` and `G=cos(x * y)`. The question looks for a solution to `f(x,y) = F-G==0`. Instead of providing that solution, you plot the solutions to `f(x,y)+0.8=0` (dark blue line), `f(x,y)+0.6 =0` (marine blue line) and so on. While you could write them as  `g1(x,y)=f(x,y)+0.8=0`, `g2(x,y) = f(x,y)+0.6=0` etc., such that each of them solves `gi(x,y)=0`, this is not what the question is about.

Comment: Ok, you just want to put a minus

Comment: No I don't want to put a minus.