# How to plot an ellipse with a self-written function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I know that there is an ellipse function in matplotlib. But I am trying to learn more Python, so I wanted to write a function for ellipse and then plot it. It turns out that I could not do it. I have this, but it does not give me an ellipse:

```py
def elipse(x,y):
    return (x - a)**2/a**2 + (y - a)**2/b**2 - 1

a = 5
b = 8
x = np.linspace(1,100)
y = np.linspace(1,100)
ell = elipse(x,y)
plt.plot(ell)
```

I would like to plot it for example giving it an origin point and a and b (width and height).

Comment: to plot the ellipse. maybe to calculate the entire Ellispe.

Comment: @mkrieger1 look at the answer. I meant something like that. I don't see why you voted my question down when it is you who did not understand it!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only create an implicit equation, you could use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/), Python's symbolic math library.  Default [`plot_implicit()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html?highlight=plot_implicit#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) will plot for `x` and `y` between `-5` and `5`, but you can change the limits.  To just show one plot, use `plot_implicit(ellipse(x, y), (x, -2, 10), (y, -2, 10))`. To create subplots, `show=False` and `PlotGrid` can be used:

```py
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit, PlotGrid, plot
from sympy.abc import x, y

def ellipse(x, y):
    return (x - a) ** 2 / a ** 2 + (y - a) ** 2 / b ** 2 - 1

a = 4
b = 3

p1 = plot_implicit(ellipse(x, y), (x, -2, 10), (y, -2, 10), axis_center=(0, 0), show=False)
p2 = plot_implicit(ellipse(x, y), (x, -2, 20), (y, -1, 7), axis_center=(0, 0), show=False)
PlotGrid(1, 2, p1, p2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Both plots show the same ellipse, with the leftmost point at `0, 4` and the topmost point at `4, 7`. If you want another ellipse, you can change the values of `a` and `b`, or change the equation in another way.

By the way, `plot_implicit` seems to default draw the x-axis at the center of the plot and the y-axis at `x=0`. Usually, sympy's plotting also draws the x-axis at `y=0`. I don't know whether this is only in the current version, but it really looks strange with the x-axis in the center. The crossing can be set explicitly as `0,0` with `axis_center=(0, 0)`.

Alternatively, you could create a grid with numpy and [plot a contour with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527/is-it-possible-to-plot-implicit-equations-using-matplotlib).

Comment: the -2 and 10 seem to be the ranges of x and y in the plot. But when I change them, the placement of the ellipse also changes although it is the same ellipse(x,y). I do not understand why that is.

Comment: The placement of the ellipse doesn't change versus the tick labels on the axes. Only as the axis limits change, a different part of the plot will be shown.  If you are in an interactive environment, you can zoom, which also changes the limits shown.

Comment: SO there is no way of getting an ellipse with giving it an origin point and a and b? still seems like the placement of the ellipse are arbitrary, as the x and y given are only for the plot ranges and not the ellipse.

Comment: Well, you gave an equation of an ellipse with center `a, a` and with `a` and `b` as half width and half height. If you want an ellipse with center `xc, yc` and with `a` and `b` as half width and half height, you could use `(x-xc)**2/a**2+(y-yc)**2/b**2-1`. To also set the limits for the plot, you could call `plot_implicit((x-xc)**2/a**2+(y-yc)**2/b**2-1, (x, xc-a, xc+a), (y, yc-b, yc+b))`.