# How to draw a bi-variate polynomial function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How is it possible to draw a quadratic bi-variate expression in Python? For example, the following expression:

```
-0.5x^2 - 0.5y^2 +0.5 xy + x + y + 0.3 = 0
```

Is it necessary to convert it to Polar system?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323187/how-to-parameterize-a-curve-fx-y

Comment: Is your question answered now?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html), Python's symbolic math library:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

x, y = symbols('x y')
plot_implicit(Eq(-0.5*x**2 - 0.5*y**2 + 0.5*x*y + x + y + 0.3, 0))
```

[image: plot_implicit]

Using numpy and matplotlib, you can create a grid of coordinates and call `plt.contour` with a contour level of 0:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1d = np.linspace(-1, 5, 50)
y1d = np.linspace(-1, 5, 50)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x1d, y1d)
f = -0.5 * x ** 2 - 0.5 * y ** 2 + 0.5 * x * y + x + y + 0.3
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contour(x, y, f, levels=[0], colors='dodgerblue')
ax.scatter(x=[0.24881, 3.75119], y=[0.24881, 3.75119], color='crimson') # draw two points in matplotlib
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you so much. How is it possible to add some points within this figure? And, also specify x and y ranges

Comment: Sympy's plotting is rather limited in graphical capabilities.  You could draw little circles to indicate points. Although internally using matplotlib, it is rather involved to invoke matplotlib functions.  A different approach is [to draw everything directly the matplotlib way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484527/is-it-possible-to-plot-implicit-equations-using-matplotlib).